# Add separate CSS for input type checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have an ASP.NET checkboxlist with "chkboxlistnames" as the class:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID ="chkName" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="chkboxlistnames" >
<asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""  ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I populate this checkbox by using jQuery, Ajax and JSON method. After rendering HTML shows like this:

```
<table id="MainContent_chkName" class="chkboxlistnames">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="MainContent_chkName_0" name="UserID" value="2009" type="checkbox">
<label for="MainContent_chkName_0">lekshmi@actsinfo.biz,Lekshmi</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(old) + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -8px;
    background: url('../img/checks.png') no-repeat 197px 1px;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 222px;
    text-align: left;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

This style is used for all checkboxes in this application, but I want a separate CSS for this checkbox using class chkboxlistnames, how to do that?

Comment: Change `input[type="checkbox"]:not(old) + label {`  as `input[class="chkboxlistnames"]:not(old) + label {`

Comment: @DavidR Why `input[class="chkboxlistnames"]` and not just use `input.chkboxlistnames`?

Comment: @godfrzero For one thing, the first is more precise; it works only on inputs with one class name.

Comment: @MrLister Not sure if that's relevant or expected in this case though. Anyway, irrelevant since the class is on the parent.

Comment: @David R after rendering class=chkboxlistnames added with class of table element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chkboxlistnames` is in the parent element, so it should be like this:

```
.chkboxlistnames input[type="checkbox"] {
    //Your CSS goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First method,

```
.chkboxlistnames input[type="checkbox"] {
   //css here
}
```

Second method,

```
#MainContent_chkName_0{
   //css here
}
```